# How to compare dates from database in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, web

I'm new to JavaScript and I'm trying to compare dates from a table generated from my database using PHP. The comparison is need to add sorting capability to the table. The JS code is as follows;

```
function sortAsc() {
var table, rows, switching, i, x, y, shouldSwitch;
table = document.getElementById("myTable");
switching = true;
while (switching) {
  switching = false;
  rows = table.rows;
  for (i = 1; i < (rows.length - 1); i++) {
    shouldSwitch = false;
    x = rows[i].getElementsByTagName("TD")[0];
    y = rows[i + 1].getElementsByTagName("TD")[0];
    if (VarDate(x.innerHTML) > VarDate(y.innerHTML)) {
      shouldSwitch = true;
      break;
    }
  }
  if (shouldSwitch) {
    rows[i].parentNode.insertBefore(rows[i + 1], rows[i]);
    switching = true;
  }
}
```

}

The format of the dates in my database is yyyy-mm-dd. Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: you can use new Date().getTime() function to compare the dates directly.

Answer (score 0):

```
let arr = [
    {name: 'test_1', date: 2623565793524},
    {name:'test_2', date: 3623965793524},
    {name:'test_3', date: 1623965793523}
]

let filtered = arr.sort((a,b)=>a.date - b.date)

console.log("result", filtered)
```

You can you use SORT for order your array
PS: ascending use `a.date - b.date` and descending use `b.date - a.date`

And if you have a UTC string, use `new Date(YOUR_DATE).getTime()`